# How to use 'sed' to add characters to beginning of line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a text file with path names (each in their own line) with either the format `./abc/def/...` or `abc/def/...`. How do I use sed to add a `./` to all files that don't start with `./`?

I've tried the following command, but it's giving me an error: 
`sed -i -E 's/^(?!\.\/.*$).*/\.\/&/g' ~/output.txt`

The error says `sed: -e expression #1, char 24: Invalid preceding regular expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed '/^[a-zA-Z]/s/\(.*\)/.\/\1/' Input_file
```

OR

```
sed '/^[a-zA-Z]/s/.*/.\/&/' Input_file
```

2nd solution:

```
sed '/^[^./]/s/^/.\//' Input_file
```

OR

```
sed '/^[^./]/s/.*/.\/&/'  Input_file
```